# Attaching a grounding pigtail to a junction without a tapped hole?

Tags: electrical, grounding

I'm trying to ground an outlet in my home to the metal of the junction box. I'm using a grounding pigtail of 14AWG wire with a 10/32 terminal attached to one end. Unfortunately it seems the metal enclosure doesn't have a tapped hole that could fit. There simply only seems to be conduit knock outs and mounting holes that are way larger to the screw in question, I'd estimate a bit less than a 1/4".

What other options do I have for connecting this grounding wire to the enclosure?

Comment: If your certain the box itself actually has ground, drill a hole and use a self-tapping screw.

Comment: Can you post a photo of the inside of the box?

Comment: @Tyson Sheet-metal screws are **specifically disallowed**.  Self-tapping screws need to be -32 or finer.  The reason is required thread engagement.

Comment: I guess I should have added ... they sell green colored self tapping screws just for this purpose.. @Harper

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are certain that the box is properly grounded, you can use [grounding clips](http://www.homedepot.com/p/Steel-Grounding-Clip-10-Pack-GEE-B10-10/202913975)

[image: grounding clip]

The wire is attached to the clip and the clip to the front edge of the box.

> Images and links are illustrative only, not an endorsement of goods or sources.

Comment: Thanks! I actually found a box with the correct 10-32 hole, but unfortunately, it seems the actual junction/conduit isn't a good ground path :(. Looks like it's time to buy a UPS for my electronics!